# Sharepoint batch for MultiChoice field value insertion

Tags: web-services, list, sharepoint, batch-file

So i have a problem regarding usage of sharepoint list webservices.

I need to get the syntax right for Sharepoint batch script for insertion of new items.
Everyhing works fine except multichoice field type.

I insert the data, but nomatter how i do it, it shows up on SP list item details OK, but when trying to edit item in SP, i see, that SP have taken the value i sent to this field as text string, and does not check the items i have saved as selected.

The script for now is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batch OnError="Return">
<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
<Field Name='SecurityCheckpoints'>1st checkpoint;2nd checkpoint</Field>
</Method>
</Batch>
```

Definition for that field is like this:

```
  <Field Type="MultiChoice" 
         DisplayName="Checkpoints allowed" 
         Required="TRUE" 
         FillInChoice="FALSE" 
         ID="{guid-guid-guid-guid-guid}" 
         SourceID="{guid-guid-guid-guid-guid}" 
         StaticName="SecurityCheckpoints" 
         Name="SecurityCheckpoints" 
         ColName="ntext2" 
         RowOrdinal="0" 
         Version="4">
          <CHOICES>
            <CHOICE>1st checkpoint</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>2nd checkpoint</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>3rd checkpoint</CHOICE>
          </CHOICES>
          <Default>1st checkpoint</Default>
        </Field>
```

I have to implement something like custom UI for sharepoint in different-purpouse silverlight app, and so i am using my own webservice to be a proxy between SP and SL, i retrieve SP list definition and dinamicaly build UI controls, so user can fill in the forms.

**How do i form the script, so items are selected(ticked) in the SP instead of SP saving them as just string value?**

**If I use script with only one item ("1st checkpoint"), SP processes it ok, it there is many, data is saved as text string?**

**What i am doing wrong? How do i correctly seperate multiple values?**

I have searched high and low, but have not found example of SP update script, where multichoice sample is included.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the sollution - it was too easy:

instead of seperating the choice values using semicolon ";", **they had to be seperated using ";#", and putting it in front and in behind the whole list.**

So rather than using this:
**1st checkpoint;2nd checkpoint**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batch OnError="Return">
<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
<Field Name='SecurityCheckpoints'>1st checkpoint;2nd checkpoint</Field>
</Method>
</Batch>
```

It had to be done like this:
**;#1st checkpoint;#2nd checkpoint;#**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batch OnError="Return">
<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
<Field Name='SecurityCheckpoints'>;#1st checkpoint;#2nd checkpoint;#</Field>
</Method>
</Batch>
```

PS:I dont know was it correct way to do this, but I answered my own question. Just for others to know.

Answer (score 0):

I run code below successfully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ows:Batch OnError="Return">
<Method ID="0"><SetList>3933c528-5747-4fc7-bdec-6465294997dd</SetList>
<SetVar Name="Cmd">Save</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="ID">New</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Temp_UNID">8D8DE35CFFE9EEEAC12570920052A8FD</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Title"> - Birch Data Exchange Specification</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#C0370A_Agora_DocNum">8AL020210178ZZASB</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#C0370A_Agora_Phase"></SetVar>
<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#C0370A_Agora_Author">Jerome BOURGER</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#C0370A_Agora_ServicesOri">  </SetVar>    
<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#C0370A_Agora_Type">;#3 - Quality Plan;#Objectives;#Progress Plan;#Follow-up;#Reports;#</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#C0370A_Agora_Keywords"></SetVar>     </Method></ows:Batch>
```